# DbContext.Entities.FromSqlRaw is not implemented?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, moq, xunit

(.Net core 3.1, EF core 3)
I have the following xUnit/Moq setup:

```
private readonly IDbContext _dbContext;

public MyTests()
{
    var contextMock = new Mock<IDbContext>();
    var dbSetMock = new List<MyEntity>
    {
        new MyEntity("...", "A"),
        new MyEntity("...", "B"),
        new MyEntity("...", "C"),
        new MyEntity("...", "D"),
    }.AsQueryable().BuildMockDbSet();
    contextMock.Setup(x => x.MyEntities).Returns(dbSetMock.Object);
    _dbContext = contextMock.Object;
}

public async Task GetValueTest()
{
    var sut = new GetValueQueryHandler(_dbContext);
    var result = await sut.Handle();
    result.IsSuccess.ShouldBeTrue();
}
```

And the in the function `GetValueQueryHandler.Handler()`, it calls

```
var ids = _dbContext.MyEntities.FromSqlRaw(sql);
```

However, it raise the error?

> The method or operation is not implemented.

```
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.RelationalQueryableExtensions.FromSqlOnQueryable[TEntity](IQueryable`1 source, String sql, Object[] parameters)
   at MockQueryable.TestAsyncEnumerable`1.CompileExpressionItem[TResult](Expression expression)
   at MockQueryable.TestAsyncEnumerable`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
   at Portal.Application.Restrictions.Queries.GetSymbolsAndTypes.GetSymbolsAndTypesQueryHandler.c__DisplayClass4_0.g__GetIds|0>d.MoveNext()
```

Answer (score 1):

The FromSql* operations are relational operations. They are meant to be invoked on a relational data source.

I assume you're using the MockQueryable package to create the mocked set. That package is just an async enumerable/async query provider implementation, it doesn't have any support for the relational operations. The Microsoft in-memory provider does not support the relational operations either.

I suspect you'll need to use a library that does provide such support. [EntityFrameworkCore.Testing](https://github.com/rgvlee/EntityFrameworkCore.Testing) does (disclaimer, I am the author), I believe there are others as well.

Comment: Do you have a nuget version that is signed?

Comment: Not at the moment